# How is it possible for the Guardians to reach Meov?

Tags: n-k-jemisin, broken-earth

In *The Fifth Season*, Alabaster and Syenite can't use their powers directly on Guardians, but they could do a lot of indirect things. For example, they could raise several stone columns in a radius from the island, forcing the Guardians to either swim to get to them or back off, buying time for Innon and people to escape. Or make a bed of razor-like spikes below the surface, then make a shake to generate a tidal difference so, when the ships approach, they break their bilges.

How is it possible for the Guardians to reach Meov?

Comment: You might get a better answer for this on science fiction & fantasy SE.

Answer (score 0):

Alabaster did not think of those solutions.

He was the majority of the defense, able to block the harbor entrance by raising rocks and fight the majority of guardian ships. After being attacked by a cannon his stone eater removed him from the battle by pulling him into the earth to prevent him from potentially being killed.

Syenite not as fully developed in her skills and exhausted became quickly overwhelmed.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Do you have an explanation of why Alabaster would not think of those solutions? An argument based on his portrayal, perhaps?

Comment: Alabaster, a rare ten ring Orogene, used his powerful and valuable position within the Fulcrum hierarchy to work outside its system of training in order to understand both Orogene enslavement and use by the Old Sanze empire, as described in his narrative arc.

The revelation of methods by which power could be used beyond the mental frameworks imposed by the Fulcrum was heretical knowledge - as rogue Orogenes were quickly killed by guardians. 

Alabaster's struggle to conceal his work and inability to work with others limited how even he could effectuate alternate energy wielding ideas.